# Retaining higher value and deleting lower value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, retain

Happy New Year.

I am unsure how to do an SQL where I need to retain the record for clientID with the highest level while deleting the others?

My Table is like below

[image: Table]

And would like to have below

[image]

Basically, it removes the duplicate clientID row but retain the highest level of that clientID record.

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, PostregSQL, SQL Server, ... ??? Please tag your question appropriately

Comment: Sorry, it did not allow me to tag to MS SQL as it was broad it says, I should have written it more precisely on the description, it is for Microsoft SQL.

Comment: Can there be multiple rows for a given `ClientID` with the same `Level` value? If so, what do you want to do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exists` as follows:

```
Delete from your_table t
  Where exists 
    (Select 1 from your_table tt
      Where tt.client_id = t.client_id and tt.level > t.level)
```

Comment: Hi Popeye, did try to use it on Microsoft SQL Server and it did not like it it says Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Completion time: 2021-01-12T12:20:08.1245183+11:00 so that is the from your_table t I used my table replacing it but still using the letter t [As]  Not sure if this is meant for Microsoft though, thank you Popeye

Comment: Share the actual query that you have used.

Answer (score 0):

In `Mysql` you can simple access the desired output without deleting the data in sql

```
SELECT ClientID,level FROM (SELECT* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID 
ORDER BY level DESC ) AS RN FROM tbl_client)A
WHERE RN=1
```

Here is the simple Desired output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I would need for those duplicates to disappear as it is creating unnecessary data, the reason for the objective